# Entity Framework 6 and Chained Relationships

Tags: entity-framework-6, foreign-keys

Having some issues with relationships within EntityFramework 6.

I know that DataAnnotations or FluentApi can be used and I'm okay with using either.

Here's an example of relationship I'd like to accomplish:

- Student has one ImmunizationRecord
- ImmunizationRecord has Multiple ShotRecords

This seems like it would be fairly straight forward, however it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

> Here's example code (Updated from actual code)

```
public class Student : Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    //...
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Id))]
    public virtual ImmunizationRecord ImmunizationRecord { get; set; }
}

public class ImmunizationRecord : Entity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Student))]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShotRecord> ShotRecords { get; set; }
}

public class ShotRecord: Entity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Want this to point back to ImmunizationRecord
    public int ImmunizationRecordId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfShot { get; set; }

    //...

    [ForeignKey("ImmunizationRecordId")]
    public virtual ImmunizationRecord ImmunizationRecord { get; set; }
}
```

> Example fluentapi might be something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasOptional(c => c.ImmunizationRecord).WithRequired(m => m.Student);
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasOptional(c => c.ImmunizationRecord).WithRequired(sc => sc.Student);
modelBuilder.Entity<ImmunizationRecord>().HasMany(sc => sc.ShotRecords).WithRequired(sr => sr.ImmunizationRecord);
```

> The Result

I suspect that I'm just missing a small piece of what needs to be done, or missing the proper way to configure these entities with a similar relationship.

With the code above and class structure, I can create a Student, and Create a ImmunizationRecord, and ShotRecords without issue.

The issue occurs when I try to retrieve the ShotRecords from The ImmunizationRecord, EntityFramework will resolve on the key on the Student.Id instead of using the key of on the ImmunizationRecord.Id.

I can go into the database and change the rows for ShotRecords and update the ImmunizationRecordId to the StudentId and they'll resolve properly.  But as stated before, I want them to use the key of the ImmunizationRecord, and not the student.

Any advice and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

(Updated to a different example to make more sense)

Comment: I updated the information a bit further with a few more data annotations that I currently have in the code.

Again for any entities, I want to achieve.

Entity1 has a One-to-One relationship with Entity2
Entity1 has a One-to-One relationship with Entity3

Entity3 has a One-to-Many relationship with Entity4

Hopefully that helps clarify things a bit!

Comment: You make `Car` the principal entity by the `WithRequired` calls. It shouldn't have foreign keys, *in this model*. But as I said before, I don't think these relationships make sense anyway. A `ServiceCenter` for only one car? I think every car owner would dream of that. In reality it's likely to be at least 1 (ServiceCenter) to n (Cars), or maybe many-to-many. Same for `CarModel`. If that is something like "SUV" then it doesn't make sense that a `CarModel` is only for one car.

Comment: Gert, thanks for your responses!  I just updated to an example that makes a little more sense.

Comment: In these 1:1 relationships parent and child have identical PK values.

Comment: There's no problem with the Student -> ImmunizationRecord.  The problem occurs when trying to link to the ImmunizationRecord -> ShotRecords.

When linking the Student -> ImmunizationRecord it uses Student.Id to ImmunizationRecord.StudentId

However, when linking the ImmunizationRecord to ShotRecords it links

ImmunizationRecord.StudentId -> ShotRecords.ImmunizationRecordId instead of linking

ImmunizationRecord.Id -> ShotRecords.ImmunizationRecordId

Hopefully this makes sense.